# How to I convert this particular class component to function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been coming with class component for a while, and so i want to change my present code to a function component so it will allow me do somethings I want to add some elements of the class component to it. But of course its not working because its different.

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: [],
        loading: false,
        hasMore: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData(res => {
        this.setState({
            data: res.results,
        });
        });
    }

    fetchData = callback => {
        reqwest({
        url: fakeDataUrl,
        type: 'json',
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: res => {
            callback(res);
        },
        });
    };

    handleAddToCart = slug => {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      authAxios
        .post(addToCartURL, { slug })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
        });
    };

    
    return;
        }
        this.fetchData(res => {
        data = data.concat(res.results);
        this.setState({
            data,
            loading: false,
        });
        });
    };

    render = (props) => {
        return (...)}
```

Please I just want to be able to have this as it is but in Function component, i have tried but its not working.

Comment: What's this `return;` in the middle of your component?

Comment: I was just trying to say some things are in the return, I felt it was not important so I deleted it and indicated that something is there with "..."

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this:

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData((res) => {
      setData(res.results);
    });
  }, []);

  const fetchData = (callback) => {
    reqwest({
      url: fakeDataUrl,
      type: "json",
      method: "get",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: (res) => {
        callback(res);
      }
    });
  };

  handleAddToCart = (slug) => {
   setLoading(true);
    authAxios
      .post(addToCartURL, { slug })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        //this.setState({ error: err, loading: false }); similar state
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: seems like you forget `const handleAddToCart`. after success `fetchData` `loading` should  be `false`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect` and `useState`:

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = React.useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    reqwest({
      url: fakeDataUrl,
      type: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: (res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setData(res.results);
      },
    });
    // return abortController.signal.abort
  // Do initial fetch when fakeDataUrl changes
  }, [fakeDataUrl]);

  const handleAddToCart = slug => {
    setLoading(true);
    authAxios
      .post(addToCartURL, { slug })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setData(`${data}${res.results}`); // concat?
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return </>;
}
```

#### Notes:

- The -commented- return value of the anonymous function passed to `React.useEffect` is used to *unsubscribe* from that effect. In this example, a correct unsubscription should be to abort the ongoing connection (out of the scope of this question/answer).
- The strange code in your questions looks like you want to concatenate `handleAddToCart` fetch result into somewhere else, but you need to take care of immutability. Clarify the question to get a better answer ;)
- The error is not being handled anywhere.
- The component does not renders anything.
- The `reqwest` method is unknown to me (typo?). Also, there is no error handling for that.